# Vertex buffers in open gl es 1.X

Tags: opengl-es

I am teaching myself about open gl es and vertex buffer (VBO) and I have written code and it is supposed to draw one red triangle but instead it colours the screen black:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

// Draw a red triangle in the middle of the screen:
glColor4f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
// Setup the vertex data:
typedef struct {
    float x;
    float y;
} Vertex;
const Vertex vertices[] = {{50,50}, {50,150}, {150,50}};
const short indices[3] = {0,1,2};
glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
NSLog(@"drawrect");
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
// The following line does the actual drawing to the render buffer:
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,  indices);
glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, framebuffer);
[eAGLcontext presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES];
}
```

Here vertexBuffer is of type GLuint. What is going wrong? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add

```
glViewport(0, 0, 320, 480);
```

where you create the frame buffer and set up the context.

And replace your call to glDrawElements with

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, ...);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your vertices dont have a Z component, try `{{50,50,-100}, {50,150,-100}, {150,50,-100}};` (your camera by default looks down the Z axis so putting it in the -Z should put it on screen) if you cant see it still try smaller numbers, im not sure what your near and far draw cutoff distance is, and if its not even set i dont know what the default is. This might not be the only issue but its the only one i can see by just looking quickly at it.

Comment: Thank you for the help! This means, even though I am only drawing in 2D on the xy-plane I have to specify a third coordinate?

Comment: @MattN. yep, opengl is a 3D graphics api, if you are trying to do 2D, you will just have to keep the Z distance equal for all objects (well roughly equal, z-fighting can occur where opengl doesnt know which object to put on top), also if you are doing  2D you should use Orthographic projection and not Perspective projection (can fiddle with that later when you have things working)

Comment: also your indices are `short` but your `glDrawElements` is expecting `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT` try use `GLushort` as your data type